# Running Windows 7 copied from old Boot camp Partition

Tags: windows-7, macos, partitioning, ntfs, boot-camp

I have a macbook pro mid 2012. I had the stock harddrive, 750 gb, with a 550 gb partition for osx and a 200 gb partition for windows/bootcamp. I got a new ssd 960 gb, with 750 gb for osx and 210 as a NTFS partion. I didn't go through the boot camp assistant because then I would have to use a windows disc that I dont have. So i used carbon copy to copy my osx files and another desktop to copy my old partition to my new one. In my macbook it only shows the osx parition as bootable not the NTFS one. I can see all the files on the NTFS partion but it wont let me boot to it when I hold down alt/option key on restart.  The NTFS partition is named SSD2, I didn't think to call it BOOTCAMP, I'm not sure if that has anything to do with it. Thanks in advance!

EDIT: I've looked into Winclone and probably am going to use that. I was just wondering if there is anyway to salvage what I've already done.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, certainly open to correction, or any Terminal method, if anyone knows one...

As far as I'm aware, the only utility capable of migrating a Bootcamp partition intact & still bootable is [Winclone](http://www.twocanoes.com/products/mac/winclone)

Comment: I might just do that, I didn't want to shell out the 40 bucks though. Or i'll do a fresh install if I find the disk.

Comment: I tried to avoid the 40 bucks too. Eventually gave up & bit the bullet. It does do its job very well, I have to say; though I've only ever actually needed it once, which makes it an expensive one-trick pony, for sure.

Comment: So could I have my old drive hooked up through usb 3 and copy the old bootcamp partition to a clean partition on the new drive? What format should the new bootcamp partition be?

Comment: I don't recall the exact procedure - but it's a bit 'light blue touch-paper & retire'… just let the app do it for you, very little user-intervention required iirc.